# reflection representation of var as opposed to an interface.

Tags: go

I am trying to understand the representation of a reflection value:

```
type S struct {
    F string `species:"gopher" color:"blue"`
}

var x float64 = 3.4
v := reflect.ValueOf(x)     
fmt.Println("v = ", v)     // v = 3.4


s := S{}
ss := reflect.ValueOf(s)
fmt.Println("ss = ", ss)   // ss = {}
```

I understand that the representation of a reflection interface value is a two-word pair that gives a pointer to type information and a pointer to the associated value.

What is the reflection representation of a variable. Is it just the value and if so, how is the type determined by code below:

```
fmt.Println("type:", reflect.TypeOf(x))
```

If the representation is just value, as it appears to be, where does the code above find the type information?

Comment: Everything you pass to reflect is in an interface. The signature of TypeOf is `func TypeOf(i interface{}) Type`

Answer (score 1):

The type of `reflect.TypeOf` is:

```
func TypeOf(i interface{}) Type
```

When you call `reflect.ValueOf(x)` in your code, the value of `x` is implicitly converted to `interface{}`. At compile time, the type of `x` is known (`float64`), and the interface value is represented as you already know; as a two word pair with the pointer to the information for `float64` and a pointer to the `float64` value (3.4).

The same reasoning applies to `s` later in your program.

There's very little implicit conversion done between types in Go, but the conversion between values and interfaces when calling a function (or assigning to a variable) is an exception.

Comment: THANK YOU !!   As I am exploring GO and I seem to find obscure questions that I can not find an answer to.  If there is a missing assumption in anything I am studying,  it seems to jump up and bite me~  Is this value to interface conversion mentioned anywhere specifically?  If so I like a reference to it.   One other question, I assume the value to interface conversion is done at compile time - Not Run-time!  Is this correct.

Comment: -----------------------One other question: ------------------------------------------------ Can I assume the value to interface conversion is done at compile time - Not Run-time!  Is this correct?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls explains how function calls work, although it's not explicitly spelled out what happens when you have a formal parameter of the function of interface type. I don't know what you mean when you ask whether it's ok to assume that the value to interface conversion is done at compile time. I don't know what it would mean to do a conversion at compile time, so I think it's necessarily done at runtime, but I suspect I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean you say there is an implicit conversion from value 'x' to implicitly converted to interface{}.  When an Where does this conversion take place.